# System Administrator? Or Systems Administrator?

Tags: untagged

I've seen both variations in job titles. Which do you use?

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: I use the version that the people that sign my paycheck tell me to put in my email signature. It is variable, and changes with employers/promotions/whims of the powers that be. (right Now it's Senior Systems Administrator). But to put my own spin on what @John said ... Who cares?

Comment: Zypher - everyone who voted up the question, to start with.

Comment: The whole industry is very confused when it comes to matching titles with resposibilities.  As an example, my current employer refers to me as Network Administrator.  I build and maintain not just our global network and network devices, but every system on it, at every site, and every other IT employee that touches it.  Title has no bearing on what we do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Systems Administrator because I look after a number of different systems whether you look at it from OS (Windows, Linux, Mac) or at an application level (more than I care to list).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're looking after one monolithic system, it's "Systems Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

It should (IMO) be "Systems." Even if you are only looking after one giant "system" you have to take into consideration enough individual aspects that are on their own individual systems.

Answer (score 0):

Systems Administrator

Answer (score 0):

It should always be Systems Administrator. Even a single computer can be considered as several systems (like for example a server running multiple virtualized OS).

My college degree has Systems Administration in it as well.